# How to fix 'Argument Z must be 2-dimensional' when plotting 3D surface using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot 3D surface based on the simple data I created in the code. However, it keeps popping up an error that Argument Z must be 2-dimensional. How do I fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig=plt.figure()
ax =Axes3D(fig) 

x=np.arange(-4,4,0.25)
y=np.arange(-4,4,0.25)

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z=np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap='rainbow')
plot.show()
```

Comment: It needs to be `Z=np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2))` instead of `Z=np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you define Z based on one-dimensional x and y. You need to use the 2D arrays created by `meshgrid`.

An example solution

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, num=0, figsize=(16, 8),
                       subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
gridY, gridX = np.mgrid[-4:4:33 * 1j, -4:4:33 * 1j]
Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(gridX ** 2 + gridY ** 2))
pSurf = ax.plot_surface(gridX, gridY, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='rainbow')
fig.colorbar(pSurf)
plt.show()
```

which displays

[image]